# How to get total count of images from google photos api

Tags: photo, google-photos, google-photos-api

Is there any way to get total count of google images using google photos api using  javascript

Answer (score 4):

This is not currently supported in the Google Photos Library API.

(As a work around, you can continue to search/list until you have received all media items and count them.)

Here's a feature request on the issue tracker to add support for this to the `mediaItems:search` request: https://issuetracker.google.com/111716613 (You can 'star' this issue to be notified of any updates and draw attention to this request.)